# If after closing fun() all the memory gets deallocated then how is the output printed

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memory

What is the output of following C program And how is the output printed when all variables of fun() after closing got their memory de-allocated.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int * fun()
{
    int q = 10;
    int *p;
    p = &q;
    return p;
}    
int main()
{
    int *res;
    res= fun();
    printf("%d", *res);
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the pointer res to point to null

Comment: This is undefined behavior.

Comment: When you do `printf("%d", *res);`, where is the `int` that you're trying to print? On which line was it made?

Comment: Memory being deallocated is not the same as setting a pointer to it to `null`.

Comment: There are several different mechanisms for memory allocation/deallocation.  Furthermore, even when memory is deallocated (that is, when you call `free` on memory that you've dynamically allocated with `malloc`, or when you return from a function so that its local memory or "stack frame" is deallocated), the key is that *the deallocated memory is typically not immediately destroyed or even made unavailable*. It's still there, at the same address, so if you have a pointer to it you can still see it -- but it might change at any time if some other part of your code allocates and starts using it..

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a pointer to an address on the stack. A reasonable compiler will give you a warning like this:

> "warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary: q"

But basically the behavior is undefined and also depends on your level of optimization.